# How remember in localstorage a appended div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with my code, because I try to do a visible appended div after refresh page or if someone go for another page.

In file .txt is code to run customer chat Facebook on my page.

My code looks like that:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.w-iconbox.iconpos_left.style_default.color_primary.no_text.ico-fbm').one('click', function (e) {
        $('<div class="facebook-chat"></div>').load("/fbchat.txt").appendTo("body")
        localStorage.setItem("fb-opened", $('.facebook-chat').html());
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('fb_dialog_mobile').click();
        }, 4000);
    })
    $('.facebook-chat').html(localStorage.getItem("fb-opened"));
})
```

Problem is that when I go for another page or refresh page, the chat div disappears -

how could I fix it to keep it in localstorage e.g. throught 5 hours?

Comment: On first glance, I see a typo: `$('facebook-chat').html()` should be `$('.facebook-chat').html()`.

Comment: @ChiragRavindra Good spot, but I wouldnt update OP's question to fix the typo. Better to leave the error in place and have it mentioned in comments/answers

Comment: @MasterYoda They didn't fix the typo in the question.

Comment: @Codeer correct, apologies to Chirag Ravindra there were actually two mentions of `$('.facebook-chat')`in OPs question and I missed one.

Comment: @ChiragRavindra Thank you for answer, but it doesn't fix problem. The div disappears
after refres page.